# Why is my computer SFOS-ing with KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE?

Tags: windows-8, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a custom built computer with an Intel i7 chipset and an nVidia 560ti. Randomly, mostly when using Google Chrome and opening new tabs / playing videos, the computer decides to SFOS (Sad Face of Sorrow) with KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE.

The only thing searching online has yielded to me is that this has something to do with a corrupted linked list in a driver somewhere. I'd like to know where to start looking in the system to figure out which driver it is (I strongly suspect nVidia) and from there figure out what I need to do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some data are corrupted and the Windows 8 kernel bugchecks the PC to prevent malicious activity:

```
**KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE (139)**
A kernel component has corrupted a critical data structure.  The corruption
could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this machine.
```

Open the dumps with WinDbg and try the steps from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj569891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx